# "The caller was not authenticated by the service" when using a customBinding only on machines on a domain

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I wrote a WCF service hosted by IIS 6 on a server that is not part of a domain. It uses the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Services.DeliveryStatsService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingWithMaxClockSkewForIncorrectlyConfiguredWindowsServer"
        contract="Services.IDeliveryStatsService" />
    </service>
  </services>

  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="BindingWithMaxClockSkewForIncorrectlyConfiguredWindowsServer">
        <binaryMessageEncoding />
        <security>
          <localClientSettings maxClockSkew="00:20:00" />
          <localServiceSettings maxClockSkew="00:20:00" />
          <secureConversationBootstrap />
        </security>
        <httpTransport />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

It would've been a simple `basicHttpBinding`, except that the server's clock is not set to the right time and its administrator will not change that, so a `customBinding` is required to allow for "clockSkew."

Clients use pretty much the same configuration (binding-wise) and can access the service without any trouble, as long as they are not part of a domain. However, clients that are part of a domain are rejected with the message "The caller was not authenticated by the service."

I turned on tracing and it would seem that the problem comes from a token exchange using SSPI negociation. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find the right configuration that will allow both machines that are not part of a domain and machines that are part of a domain to access the service. I have tried several values for `authenticationMode`, without avail. What's more, as far as I'm concerned, I don't need any particular security on this service.

WCF configuration is far from being my specialty and I haven't found an answer anywhere else, so I hope someone at Stack Overflow will be able to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should've specified that clients are supposed to access the service anonymously. No credentials are passed. Even so, it works when machines are not part of a domain and it doesn't when they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to set `maxClockSkew` when you don't need security? It is for handling time differences in timestamps which are not send without security. Once you add `security` element you turn on authentication because all attributes in the element have default values. Default value for mode is `sspiNegotiated`. I would start with removing `security` element.

Comment: Removing the `security` element resulted in a new exception. I do not have access to a machine on the domain during the weekend, but I'll post more info first thing on Monday. Thanks.

Comment: I accepted this as an answer because it indeed solved my problem, but if somebody can explain why "anonymous behavior" worked when not on a domain machine and didn't on a domain machine, without completely removing security, I wouldn't mind the explanation ;)

Comment: madd0: It can have something to do with sspiNegotiated and configuration of domain machine.